# JMeter authenticity token with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jmeter

I am trying to do a JMeter post operation to a simle rails app but I am getting the following back:

Started POST "/flights/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-04 12:40:15 -0700
Processing by FlightsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"$(LOGIN_AUTH_TOKEN)"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

I have implemented the suggestion about creating a regular expression extractor for the authenticity login as shown here:

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

and here is the http request:

[image: http post request]

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance,
Slavko

Comment: Why was this question downvoted??

Answer (score 1):

- Move the `Regular Expression Extractor` as the child element of the first HTTP Request.
- Regular expression could be `name=authenticity_token type=hidden value=(.*?)"`
- In the next request, access authenticity_token by using `${LOGIN_AUTH_TOKEN}`   (Not by $(LOGIN_AUTH_TOKEN))

Comment: In my case it still remains the same, following is the response in console
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"${FORM_AUTH_TOKEN}"}

Comment: Also don't forget to put  HttpCookieManager to your ThreadGroup because Rails save checks the token against the one in the session, which is typically in a cookie.

Comment: And not sure if JMETER doesn't do it by itself but I had to encode the extracted token as `${__urlencode(${FORM_AUTH_TOKEN})}`

Comment: @Jakub you saved my day, it is finally working. Thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

I think Vinoth was right, but it looks like only the request headers were being checked. The form field is in the body, so the Regex Processor should look there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by inspecting the source of my rendered pages and modifying my regular expression accordingly.

I searched the source for "authenticity" and here's what it yielded:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="O4YJPTDTmHqxAtgVYLTyDnuo1gwNoDQFznnqwsUyvdMkJscVXx+YMteKkuMVG44E/H6NYCdi/RzbQ8oIly2euA==" />
```

I changed my regular expression inside jMeter's Regular Expression Extractor to: `meta name="csrf-token" content="(.*?)" />`

I then ran my jMeter test and it logged into my development application successfully.

I'm on Rails 4.2.1 and Ruby 2.2.1p85.